# ST_Clip tiled raster using geometry results in out of geometry pixels

Tags: postgis, clip, postgis-raster

I'm trying to run an ST_Clip for a simple AOI geometry.

I'm using [this WGS84 raster](https://storage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC-2016-v1.4/Hansen_GFC-2016-v1.4_lossyear_20S_070W.tif), imported into PostGIS like so:

`raster2pgsql -t 100x100 -C -M -F -I -s 4326 Hansen_GFC-2016-v1.4_lossyear_20S_070W.tif hansen_temp | psql`

I'm trying to clip this raster to my AOI (gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/a908896c0341d67eaa84fce12e1ebca5)).

I use ogr2ogr to insert this AOI into postgres:

`ogr2ogr -f Postgresql PG:"dbname=charlie" aoi.geojson`

I run the following SQL:

`CREATE TABLE ras_clip AS 
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast, wkb_geometry ))
            FROM hansen_temp, aoi
            WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, wkb_geometry)) foo;`

This results in a raster that seems to follow my AOI - perhaps following the 100x100 tiles I set when importing the data using raster2pgsql. Here's a screenshot taken from PostGIS:

[image: Example raster overlap]

Is this the desired results of ST_Clip? Is there any way to constrain the output to only pixels that actually intersect the geometry of interest?

PostGIS version info:
`POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6" PROJ="Rel. 5.0.1, April 1st, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.0, released 2018/05/04" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13.1" RASTER`

Comment: Your query looks correct, other than the unecessary SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... which you could just replace with SELECT ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast, geom)..... It isn't very clear from your question how what you have done isn't working. A screen shot of the aoi, might be more useful than the gist.

Comment: It is possible you should be using the ST_Clip (rast, geom, no_data_value, true) form, ie, explicitly cropping which requires setting a no data value.

Comment: Hi @JohnPowellakaBarça - thanks so much for your response. You were exactly right - adding the no data value and explicitly cropping did the trick. Please post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Charlie, sure, done. The Postgis raster functions are really great, but there are some quite non-obvious things.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I don't know if you read the answer in full, no problem either way :D, but the DumpAsPolygons or PixelAsPolygons might be of use to you. I don't know what analysis you are doing exactly, but for irregular areas where you just want to convert raster to vector, this works really well.

Comment: Hi John, I did I did- will check out those two functions as well. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various forms of the [ST_Clip function](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html). To remove areas outside of your polygonal aoi, you should use one of the forms with an explicit **no data** value -- appropriate to whatever software you will be utilizing to view/analyse the clipped raster -- with **clipped** set to **true**, eg, this one:

> raster ST_Clip(raster rast, geometry geom, double precision nodataval, boolean crop=TRUE);

Your query then becomes something like:

```
CREATE TABLE ras_clip AS 
SELECT 
      ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast, wkb_geometry, -9999, true))
  FROM hansen_temp, aoi
 WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, wkb_geometry);
```

Note also, you don't need the subselect, as you are doing `SELECT * FROM (` so you can just run a single select, although I am sure the query planner would do that automatically. Less typing is always good, though :D.

You might also want to look at [ST_DumpAsPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html) or [ST_PixelAsPolygons](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsPolygons.html), depending on how you are doing your analysis. For raster coverages that are clipped to a very irregular polygon that cover little of the original raster coverage -- think rivers, train lines, etc -- it is sometimes more efficient to convert the output of ST_Clip to a polygonal coverage, as you don't have to store all the no data values.